# $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$ is not a PID? Proof correction?

Tags: ring-theory

> Prove or disprove the following: The ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$ is a PID.

Going over some questions from a course I took recently, I want to see if I am understanding this problem well.

My claim is no, it is not a PID. I take the ideal generated by $2,5$ say
$$I=\{ 2x+5y \mid x,y \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]\}.$$
I claim that this ideal is not principal. I say suppose $I=(x)$ for some $x\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$, so as $2,5 \in (x)$, we have $2=xk$ and $5=xm$. Therefore, $10=5xk=2xm$. As $x\neq 0$ and we are in an integral domain we have cancellation so $5k=2m$. In this case, $2$ and $5$ are associates, which implies by a theorem we have that $(2)=(5)$ but then $2 \in (5)$ so $2=5(a+i\sqrt{19}b)$ but this implies $5a=2$ but then $a \notin \mathbb{Z}$ so we have a contradiction so $I$ is not principal.

My question is am I missing anything or does this look good?

Comment: I seem to remember that this was an exam problem : show that it is a non euclidean PID...

Comment: $5k=2m$ does not mean $2$ and $5$ are associates

Comment: I do not see any relation of $19$ with $2$ and $3$... so if you think this is fine.. except for one/two almost all should not be PIDs.... DO you think this could be possible somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ No, in every ring $\,(\color{#0a0}5,\color{#c00}2) = 1\,$ since it contains $\,\color{#0a0}5-2\cdot\color{#c00}2 = 1$.

Recall that PIDs are integrally closed, i.e. they satisfy the monic case of RRT = Rational Root Test (the standard proof uses only gcds, which exist in PIDs since $(a,b) = (c)\iff c =\gcd(a,b)).$

So, for example $\,\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ is not a PID since it fails monic RRT:  $\,x^3-1$ has a fractional root $(-1+\sqrt{-3})/2\, $ that is a *proper* fraction, i.e.$\,\not\in R.\,$  An analogous proof works in your case.